# CLMM Pool on Raydium

Tags: solana-program, raydium, dex

I'm confused about creating a pool on CLMM on Raydium. I'm using the Raydium SDK to create a DEX, but I'm stuck understanding the addresses involved.

As far as I understand, there are three main functions: CLMM pool creation, CLMM position creation, and Adding a position. First, the user has to create the CLMM pool, then create a position, and finally, anyone can come and add to the position.

Am I correct? If so, what is the for adding a position? I can't understand.

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/clmmCreatePool.ts

Could you help clarify the process and how the addresses are used in each step?

Answer (score 0):

CreatePosition is a function where you define the position property (pool, price range) and then add liquidity to it.
/ You can't create an empty position.

AddPosition is a function allowing the operator to add liquidity to an existing position. It will not let you reset the position parameters.
/ AddPosition is a cheaper function to use than CreatePosition if you intend to deploy liquidity on the range of an existing position since you won't be minting a new NFT and paying Metaplex fees.

Hope this answers your first question :)

What is your question regarding addresses?